# JAX-RS Jersey Maven HTTP Status 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: maven, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm new to JAX-RS and I've created a Maven project but when I try and invoke my service I get the following server status on Tomcat

> HTTP Status 404: The origin server did not find a current
>   representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose
>   that one exists.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lymedo.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestService Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.aether/aether-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>RestService</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app> 

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.lymedo</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Service

```
package com.lymedo;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/service")
public class Service {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello(){

        return "Hello!";

    }

}
```

[image: Project Structure]

I'm using Postman to test the service with the following URL: 
http://localhost:8080/RestService/rest/service/hello

So I'm assuming it's a mapping issue and Tomcat can't find the class where the service is declared??

I'm hoping it is something obvious. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more than just `jersey-server`. The main one you need is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you!! :) I thought I had all of the dependencies with the server-core...clearly not! A more thorough read of the documentation next time I think.